# Prove the following represents a circle

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, circles

I'm trying to prove the following represents a circle but I can't see how to reduce it down to the form $|z-z_0|=c$:

Let $r \in \mathbb{R}, r \not= 0, c \in \mathbb{R}, k \in \mathbb{C} : |k|^2>cr$
Prove $r|z|^2 - \bar{k}z - k \bar{z} + c = 0$ represents a circle

Comment: Just write $z=x+iy,k=a+ib$.

Comment: @fleablood. Why?

Comment: Thank you! Would I be right in saying the radius is $(\frac{a^2+b^2-rc}{r}) ^{0.5}$?

Comment: Careless.  I should have noted that $\overline k z = \overline {k \overline x}$.  (work it out) so $\overline k z - k \overline z = 2Re(k\overline z)$.